# Docker can't find generated jar file

Tags: java, docker

I can't figure out why Docker can't find the created `jar` file in the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:latest

ENV APP_HOME=/app/

COPY pom.xml $APP_HOME
COPY src $APP_HOME/src/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN mvn package -DskipTests
ENV JAR_FILE=target/spring-boot-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

EXPOSE 8300
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

when building the image with: `docker build -t spring-boot-app .`, it fails with:

```
Step 9/11 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder834657272/target/spring-boot-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

If I run `mvn clean package` before building the image, it works. If remove `target` folder as `rm -rf target` and rebuild the image, it fails.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to copy your locally built jar file to the image, but most probably you just want to move the jar file you build inside the image to another path?

Just replace the `COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar` with `RUN mv ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar`

Comment: I believed that the Maven built was run inside a container, so the generated `jar` would be also created inside. I wonder why Docker does not see it. So `COPY` is applied to the existing locally files only? Not inside the container?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Have a look at the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy (=> `The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from <src> and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path <dest>.`) - there is a slight difference between `ADD` and `COPY` but it essentially performs the same task

Comment: COPY is the right command to use. The location of Dockerfile is important vis-à-vis the target/*.jar